# How to align dynamically generated divs or paragraphs

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want to display a product page with every item aligned with each other. These products are dynamically generated using PHP code. The problem is, they won't align horizontally when one product has a longer name than the other.

**To further understand my problem, here is a screenshot:**
[image: Product misalignment screenshot]

You can see that the product prices are not aligned with each other because they are influenced by the length of the product names.

**Here is my PHP and HTML code:**

```
<!--PHP CODE FOR EXTRACTING DATA FROM TABLE-->
<div class="span_container">
                        <div class="col-md-4 bottom-cd simpleCart_shelfItem" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <div class="product-at ">
                                <a href="single.php"><img class="img-responsive" style="width:300px; height:auto;" src="/EDGE/storeadmin/product_images/<?php echo $row['i_image']; ?>" alt="">
                                <div class="pro-grid">
                                            <span class="buy-in">View Details</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <p class="tun"><?php echo $row['i_name'];?></p>
                            <a href="checkout.php" class="item_add"><p class="number item_price"><i> </i>₱<?php echo $row['i_price']; ?></p></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**And this is the CSS code of my paragraph (tun):**

```
    p.tun {
    font-size:1em;
    color: #949494;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: fixed max height to `<p>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple. Set `position:relative;` for the containing `.simpleCart` class, and a height like `height:300px` - replace 300 with whatever your box height needs to be so every containing box has the same height.

Then use `position:absolute;` to position the elements within `.simpleCart` according to the heights that we know already.

We know and can deduce:

- the height of the image: therefore we use, as an example: `position:absolute;top:5%;` - change 5% according to your needs.
- the height of the product prices and that those will be at the bottom no matter how high the .simpleCart box will be. So we use `position:absolute;bottom:5%` - change 5% according to your needs, again. Now every product price is at the same level. Provided that every `.simpleCart` box is of the same height.
- Finally, we place the paragraph text with the `.tun` class in between with `position:absolute;top:150px;` - where you change 150 according to your needs so it fits between the image and the product pricing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following js function to match the module heights to the tallest.

```js
equalheight = function(container){

var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;
 $(container).each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   $($el).height('auto')
   topPostion = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);
   } else {
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
  }
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }
 });
}

$(window).load(function() {
  equalheight('.equalise-height');
});
```

Comment: Obviously you'd just apply this to your .simpleCart_shelfItem classes. It's also responsive if you run this on a window.resize function too.